# Is the projection from a Zariski product of Zariski closed subsets an open map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb A^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb A^m$ be Zariski closed.  Then the (Zariski) product $X \times Y \subseteq \mathbb A^{n + m}$ is closed and there is a projection map $p\colon X \times Y \to X$ which is continuous in the Zariski topology.

**Question:** *When is $p$ an open map?*

This is always the case when $X \times Y$ is given the product topology but here we give it the Zariski product topology and when we do that the result is not always true.  I know it's true when $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible and the field is algebraically closed.  Martin gave a very short answer to that effect [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126745/are-the-projection-morphisms-from-a-product-of-varieties-necessarily-open) (and if someone could point me too a more elementary proof in that case I would appreciate it).  The projection $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ onto the first coordinate is not open (look at the complement of a circle) so even when $X$ and $Y$ are irreducible we need the field to be algebraically closed.  What about when the field is algebraically closed but $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily irreducible?

Comment: The title and the body ask different questions. At least to the unsuspecting eye of someone unfamiliar with the term Zariski product.

Comment: Your question has been answered in the linked mathoverflow discussion. So actually you are looking for a more direct proof?

Comment: There is an elementary proof in the case of a projection map. First, it is enough to prove the projection $A^n\times A^1\to A^n$ ($m=1$) is open. It is also enough to prove the image of a principal open subset $D(f)$ is open. Write $f=a_0+a_1T+\cdots a_dT^d$ and let $(x,t)\in D(f)$. Then some $a_i(x)\ne 0$ and $D(a_i)$ is contained in $p(D(f))$: for all $x'\in D(a_i)$, $f(x',t)$ is a non-zero polynomial, hence $f(x',t_0)\ne 0$ for some $t_0$. This means that $(x',t_0)\in D(f)$ and $x'\in p(D(f))$.

Comment: @user18119: This is not a comment, it is an answer.

Comment: I realize now what was confusing me.  My example of a circle in $\mathbb R^2$ shows that the projection is not *closed*, but it is indeed open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the projection $p:X\times Y\to X$ is always an open map.
This follows from the following purely algebraic fact:

**Theorem**
Given two algebras $R,S$ over a field $k$, the projection morphism $Spec(R\otimes_k S)\to Spec(S)$ is open.

Note that there are no finiteness conditions on the algebras.
The proof can be found in De Jong and collaborators'  [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/book.pdf), Lemma 9.38.10.
A more advanced  geometric interpretation of this result is that for a scheme $X$ over a field $k$, the structural morphism $X\to Spec(k)$ is universally open.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the Lemma http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/037G (which I would not see as purely algebraic). Note that the proof directly reduces to the theorem which I was refering to in the linked mathoverflow discussion http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126745, which is a consequence of Chevalley's theorem.